# JQUERY. How can i toggle between 'none' and 'block'?

Tags: jquery, css

Consider the following markup.

```
<div class="sweet-overlay" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 1;display: none;"></div>
```

How can i toggle the style from `none` to `block` and vice versa?

Comment: `$(".sweet-overlay").toggle()` ?

Comment: When should it be changed? On click, hover, etc? What have you tried? This seems pretty trivial.

Comment: @j08691 Actually this should occur before and after an ajax postpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('.sweet-overlay').toggle();

Info: [.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
.sweet-overlay{display:none;} 
.sweet-overlay.active{display:block}
```

jquery

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.sweet-overlay').toggleClass('active');
});
```

example:

https://jsfiddle.net/andrebrandaoo/ojfvwwLo/